# Upgrade Nginx version 1.18 to 1.25 latest version in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-20.04

I am following this [medium page](https://medium.com/@soban1193/upgrading-nginx-to-the-latest-version-on-ubuntu-c0ad9116cf87) to upgrade the Nginx version.
But, it is still showing the 1.18 version after I upgrade.

```
soubhagya.pradhan@FALAIDEDEV01:~$ nginx -v
nginx version: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
```

I got no error in the process too. How I can upgrade Nginx to the latest version?

I am expecting this to be upgraded to the latest version.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please add the steps you did and not just refer to another page.

Answer (score 4):

To avoid building it from sources, you can use ready-made packages of nginx for certain Linux distros as described [here](https://nginx.org/en/linux_packages.html), e.g. [for Ubuntu](https://nginx.org/en/linux_packages.html#Ubuntu) (only 20.04, 22.04, 22.10 and 23.04 Ubuntu versions are supported now). You will need to set up the nginx packages repository (instead of or in addition to your distro's default repositories).

Version `1.25.*` of nginx is currently available in "mainline" repo (`http://nginx.org/packages/mainline/ubuntu`, not `http://nginx.org/packages/ubuntu`). But keep in mind that this may change over time.

Answer (score 0):

The latest version that the ppa:nginx/stable repository has is 1.18, as you can see here:

[https://launchpad.net/~nginx/+archive/ubuntu/stable](https://launchpad.net/%7Enginx/+archive/ubuntu/stable)

So that's why you are getting this version.

Comment: How can i upgrade to 1.25 version ?

Comment: In your current Ubuntu release, you can only upgrade to 1.18.0. If you insist to install the latest version, you can always compile from source: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/install/ (not recommended though, no auto updates)

Comment: I have a question about this. Isnt nginx 1.18.0 very old and contains lots of security exploits? The last version was from 2020. How would this be secure?

Comment: @M.H. There is always a tradeoff between stability/ease of maintenance and security.

Comment: @M.H. : in reality, you don't get the v1.18.0 version exactly. The officiel repos from Ubuntu include security patches. You get, in fact, version " 1.18.0-6ubuntu14.4" or latter.  As you can see here: https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/22.04/ubuntu-updates-main-amd64/nginx_1.18.0-6ubuntu14.4_amd64.deb.html in the changelogs (at the bottom of the page), that package has been maintained since 2020 and gets security patches. 

This is a common practice in the Linux ecosystem, for stability reasons, they don't upgrade packages to the latest versions, but they keep them up to date with the security patches.